# pymc3 import switch does not work

Tags: python, pymc, pymc3, bayesian-networks

I'm new to pymc3 and tried to import the switch method with

`from pymc3 import switch`,

but I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a48d5328031b> in <module>()
----> 1 from pymc3 import switch

ImportError: cannot import name 'switch'
```

Does anybody have an idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from pymc3.math import switch` should work.

`from theano.tensor import switch` should also work.